# Using VLC to play DVDs, get Green screen

Tags: 16.04, vlc, dvd, ubuntu-mate, apple

First of all VLC wouldn't play DVDs at all, then I downloaded a recommended library.  It now trys top play the DVD, but I get a Green screen.  Audio is fine.

Running Ubuntu-MATE 16.05 on G5 Mac PowerPC

Comment: What graphics card do you have in that G5 Mac PowerPC?

Comment: Just says mac 20" under hardware, nothing specific.  Is there any specific way to find out?  On bootup it does mention something about radeon

Answer (score 3):

I had the green-screen issue on Xubuntu 17.04 and fixed it via the following:

1. In VLC select **Tools -> Preferences**
2. Select the **Input/Codecs** tab
3. Change the **Hardware-accelerated decoding** option to **Disable**